# How can I use the authagraph projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, reprojection-mathematics

I have only been able to find [this resource which reproduces the authagraph projection and it is compiled in C](https://marcinciura.wordpress.com/2016/11/20/authagraph/).

Is there any way I can use this resource to make an authagraph projected map in QGIS?

Is there another way the authagraph can be made in QGIS?

Comment: Can you link us to the "resource"?

Comment: @SpacedMan the resource is now linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use that in QGIS as any other projection you'd need to compile QGIS with a PROJ.4 library that had the author's code added to it. This has been asked in the comments on that page.

If rebuilding QGIS is too much, it would be easier to build just PROJ.4 and convert your shapefiles/etc outside QGIS using the PROJ.4 command line utilities, but then you'd not be able to use QGIS' projection-on-the-fly facilities.

I'm not sure if PROJ.4 is static- or dynamic-linked with QGIS (might be system dependent) so maybe you can build a PROJ.4 with that "authagraph" projection and it will get linked in dynamically.

I don't know what the PROJ.4 developers attitudes are to adding new projection types is, but you might have to wait for that to happen if you can't do all the recompilation needed.

Comment: I did just build a PROJ.4 with the code, but when run QGIS with it I can't add an authagraph projection to the Custom CRS list, even though I can do a test projection in the Custom CRS dialog. I've pinged the QGIS-dev emailing list for help and hopefully suggestions. I suspect it might need a full QGIS recompilation...